# How to raise Notifications on new discussion posts?

Tags: distributions

How do I enable notifications for a user who subscribes to a Discussion Post section so that the user gets a notification when a new discussion topic is created by another user?

The notification should show up on his profile dashboard as well as sent by email.

Presently, the user dashboard has the block View - [Open Atrium](https://www.drupal.org/project/openatrium) Content - Recently Updated Subscribed Content, but this block only shows updates for new comments on specifically subscribed content topics, not new discussion topics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flag module to create "subscribe button" on any content (forum category, post or comment) and then Rules to create rule:

1. what reacts to new content
2. then load parent entity (if new post, load it's category)
3. load all flaggings on it
4. send e-mails to authors of all flaggings OR create notification (so you can show them on some dashboard)

There are also modules specialized for subscribing to content and then send notifications, but they usually are not so flexible like solution based on Rules.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Message Stack](https://www.drupal.org/node/2180145), these are the basic components and dependencies of it:

[image]

Some more details about the Message-related modules (=quotes are from the module's project page):

- [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message):

  > The Message module is the core of the message stack. It enables logging and displaying system events in a number of different use cases. Events that are recorded over time are sometimes call activity streams. Exportable messages subtypes can be created for different use cases with custom fields and display (view) modes.
- [Message Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_notify).

  > This module provides a method for sending a message via a notifier plugin. Message Notify comes with plugins for email and SMS and may be extended to other transport mechanisms as required.
- [Message Subscribe](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_subscribe).

  > With this module, users who subscribe to content will be notified when events occur that involve that content. The module leverages the Flag module, which provides a subscribe functionality to users.

Quite a few popular Drupal distributions already adopted to this Message Stack, [Open Atrium](https://www.drupal.org/project/openatrium) is one of them.